# PHP Create document copy on server when a document is generated

Tags: php, mysql, file, download, copy

In my application, the user can create a receipt according to the rent items.

I use this code to create a Word file (.doc) out of an exisiting template.

```
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=Rent_Receipt_". $_SESSION['custid']    .".doc");
        include ("templates/template_receipt.php");
```

Now the user will have this stored on his local computer, but how can I make the server to store this same document in the server folder, so the user don't have to upload it manually?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
The include: template_receipt.php contains HTML code for the Word document to be created:

```
<?php echo "
<html xmlns:v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml'
xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'
xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word'
xmlns:m='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml'
xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content='text/html; charset=windows-1252'>
<meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document>
<meta name=Generator content='Microsoft Word 14'>
<meta name=Originator content='Microsoft Word 14'>
<link rel=File-List href='Template%20Verhuurbon_files/filelist.xml'>
<link rel=Edit-Time-Data href='Template%20Verhuurbon_files/editdata.mso'>
<link rel=dataStoreItem href='Template%20Verhuurbon_files/item0001.xml'
target='Template%20Verhuurbon_files/props002.xml'>
<link rel=themeData href='Template%20Verhuurbon_files/themedata.thmx'>
<link rel=colorSchemeMapping
href='Template%20Verhuurbon_files/colorschememapping.xml'>
```

And so on. I'm going to look into this `ob*_` in a second. Thank you for fast response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ob_*` functions will help.
For example:

```
<?php
    // geting file content
    ob_start();
    include ("templates/template_receipt.php");
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    //store in local file
    file_put_contents('/file/name.txt',$content);

    // file output:
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=Rent_Receipt_". $_SESSION['custid']    .".doc");
    echo $content;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not showing the code that actually sends the content to the user, but the general idea is that you should [turn on output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and capture the generated document, e.g:

```
ob_start();
include ("templates/template_receipt.php");
$document = ob_get_clean();
```

After doing this you can send the document to the user with a simple `echo $document` and at the same time save it locally with something like `file_put_contents('local_copy', $document)`.